# Laravel 5.1 store cookie and share with other page issue

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5.1

I am trying to save some data to the cookie and store it user's browser. So first, i created this code:

```
$view = view('config', compact('vehicleConfig');
    return response($view)->withCookie('fff', $cookie, 3);
```

But this is storing in response cookie, so i can't reach that from other pages such as home..

But instead of these codes, this code writes to the request code and i can reach it from everywhere:

```
$response->withCookie(cookie('retrox', 'valuex', 60));

return $response;
```

So, if i use "view" i can't reach to cookie data from other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you retrieve just like this:

```
$retrox_value = Cookie::get('name');
```

and store just like this:

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
```

Comment: i can't reach 'fff' cookie, not 'retrox'

Comment: i just give an example. please check again

Comment: i can reach the first cookie but not second cookie.

Comment: kindly turn off the secure flag. if you are not using https.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use session helper function like this:

Store:

```
session('key', 'val');
```

Retrieve:

```
echo session('key');
```

As its stored in session, you can access it from every where in your code.

Comment: i just want to use cookie because user must reach the cookie in certain time.

Comment: @yigitozmen If you set a cookie at current response, you can access it from next request.

Comment: how can i set a cookie reachable in all page of site?